# pluginlib terminates when there are no plugins

Tags: ros, pluginlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to create a scenario where I have one package ("the_exec") that defines an interface the_exec::AEIF and depending on a configuration file loads some plugins.

When I create just the interface and a simple main this line doesn't work:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    pluginlib::ClassLoader<the_exec::AEIF> poly_loader("the_exec", "the_exec::AEIF");
```

and gives me:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'pluginlib::LibraryLoadException'
  what():  rospack could not find the the_exec package containing the_exec::AEIF
```

This happens even when I do not try to load any plugins.

However, when I define one simple package that contains plugins, even if they are not being loaded it works fine.
I cannot guarantee that there are plugins available for this package as they are plugins to be defined optionally, so the program should work without any plugins.

I could probably fix this by defining a dummy plugin in the the_exec package, but I'm wondering if there is a better cleaner way or how to fix this properly.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11944/pluginlib-terminates-when-there-are-no-plugins/) by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31395 on 2011-11-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OK, the error output is a little misleading. `rospack plugins` returns nothing (no implementations of the interface found), and pluginlib has no way to distinguish this from "couldn't find the package containing the interface."

Can't you just catch the exception?

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Mihelich](https://answers.ros.org/users/180/patrick-mihelich/) with karma: 4336 on 2011-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-11-15**:
That somehow makes sense. The package is the same that defines the interface, i.e. the_exec package contains the_exec::AEIF. I even tried instatiating a dummy implementation, but I guess it needs to be registered like a plugin. I can catch the exception for now and interpret that as "no plugins".